# What is the difference between datum and query in bloodhound search engine?

Tags: typeahead.js, bloodhound

So I am trying to build something using bloodhound search engine and I noticed that it has these two tokenisers, datum and query.

The initializer code example given in the documentation looks like this:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  local: ['dog', 'pig', 'moose'],
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace
});
```

What do these two Tokenizers do?

**EDIT**

[Bloodhound documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md) defines these two as follows:

**datumTokenizer** – A function with the signature (datum) that transforms a datum into an array of string tokens. Required.

**queryTokenizer** – A function with the signature (query) that transforms a query into an array of string tokens. Required.

It still doesn't explain what is the difference between a Datum and a Query.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## On Datum and Query

`datum` are the elements of the index that is *searched thru an*d the `query` is what is being *searched for*.  If either contain more than one *token(s)* (or word when `whitespace` is used), the engine needs some [function to split characters on](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#options).  See more info on [why tokenization is needed](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/migration/0.10.0.md#tokenization-methods-must-be-provided).

Comment: what's a index in this context?

Comment: @user17282 Like an index in the back of a book, it is the list of words being searched through.

Comment: So if my server returns "php" "programming" "perl" then the three of them together are index ?

Comment: @user17282 yea, I used the term loosely, as in *some* general [index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index#Computer_science).